# Must large (infinite) groups have large automorphism groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cardinals, automorphism-group

For every cardinal $\kappa$, is there a cardinal $\lambda$ such that for all groups $G$ with $|G| > \lambda$, we have $|\mathrm{Aut}(G)| > \kappa$? I believe a similar result holds for finite groups (see [Groups with given automorphism groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512424/groups-with-given-automorphism-groups)), but I'm wondering about the infinite case. If this fails, how badly does it fail? Are there arbitrarily large groups with finite automorphism group?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting from [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300715/groups-with-finite-automorphism-groups) about infinite groups with finite automorphism groups, I quickly landed in the following paper:

J.T. Hallet and K.A. Hirsch, [*Torsion-free groups having finite automorphism groups I*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869365900104), J. Algebra **2** (1965) 287-298.

In the introduction, they say:

> Preliminary results by de Groot [7], Hulanicki [10], Fuchs [5], and Saqiada [11] showed successively that for every cardinal 
>   number $r$ less than $2^{\aleph_0}$, $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, $2^{2^{2^{\aleph_0}}}$ there are torsion-free abelian groups $G$ of rank $r$ with $|\mathrm{Aut} (G)|  = 2$, and in 1959 Fuchs [6] stated that there is no restriction whatever on the cardinal number $r$ of the rank of such a group. True, a flaw in Fuchs’ argument was revealed by Corner [3], but he at least was able to save the result for all ranks $r$ smaller than the hypothetical first “strongly inaccessible” cardinal number.

The interest of the article is to find which finite groups occur as automorphism groups of infinite groups, so they do not appear to go further into this. But note that since the existence of strongly inaccessible cardinals is unprovable in ZFC, I expect you would need to go to model theory and play with variants of large cardinal axioms in order to be able to get an affirmative answer to your question, even for $\kappa=2$.

ADDED: Jeremy Rickard has pointed out in comments that Saharon Shelah removed the restriction on $\lambda$ being less than the first strongly inaccessible cardinals in 1974, nine years after the paper I am quoting. So the answer to the question is an inequivocal “no”, since it fails for $\kappa=2$.

Comment: Fascinating! I would be really curious about if my statement is consistent with ZFC (or even provable from large cardinal axioms), although I don't really know any of the relevant math!

Comment: @BGunsolus Honestly, this is well outside the kind of group theory I do. The paper I’m citing is over 55 years old, though. If I wanted to see if something more is known now, I would probably look through the work of Saharon Shelah, who has done a lot of work in precisely that kind of “group theory under sundry large cardinal existence axioms”.

Comment: @BGunsolus Also look at *Torsion-free Abelian groups with finite groups of automorphisms* by V. A. Nikiforov where it is shown that for any infinite cardinal there are many abelian groups of that cardinality with automorphism group the cyclic group in two generators (lemma 3).

Comment: @PaulPlummer: Sorry: what does “the cyclic group in two generators” mean? Cyclic groups, by definition, are $1$-generated.

Comment: I ment cyclic group of order two... Also I am looking at the paper a bit more and lemma 3 might be a typo, I think the extra condition that the cardinals are less than the first measurable one still applies

Comment: The restriction on the cardinality was removed by Shelah in *Infinite Abelian groups, the Whitehead problem and some constructions, Israel J. Math., 18(1974), 243–256*.

Comment: @JeremyRickard: Thanks! Nice to know (and nice to know I was right about where to look...)